# Calculate bond yield to maturity (YTM) in C++

Tags: c++, finance, quantitative-finance, computational-finance

I want to calculate bond's yield to maturity given price using either the bisection or the secant method. I know there's C++ recipes online for this, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my own code. Both methods create an infinite loop. When I tried to step through variables, the yield to maturity iterative solutions keep increasing to 80% and higher.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class bond {
private:
    double principal;
    double coupon;
    double timeToMaturity;

public:
    bond(double principal, double coupon, double timeToMaturity) {
        this->principal = principal;
        this->coupon = coupon;
        this->timeToMaturity = timeToMaturity;
    }

    double getprice(double YTM);
    double getytm(double price);
    double getytmsec(double price);
};

bool isZero(double x)
{
    if (fabs(x) < 1e-10)
        return true;
    return false;
}

double bond::getprice(double YTM) {
    double pvPrincipal;
    double pvCoupon;
    double factor = 0;

    pvPrincipal = this->principal / pow(1 + YTM, this->timeToMaturity);

    for (int i = 0; (this->timeToMaturity - i) > 0; i++) {
        double denom = pow(1 + YTM, this->timeToMaturity - i);
        factor += 1 / denom;
    }

    pvCoupon = this->coupon * factor;

    return pvPrincipal + pvCoupon;
}

// Bisection method
double bond::getytm(double price) {
    double low = 0;
    double high = 1;

    double f0 = getprice(low);
    double f2 = 1;
    double x2 = 0;

    while (!isZero(f2)) {
        x2 = (low + high) / 2;
        f2 = getprice(x2) - price;
        if (f2 < 0) {
            low = x2;
        }
        else {
            high = x2;
        }
    }

    return x2;
}

// Secant method
double bond::getytmsec(double price) {
    double x1 = price;
    double x2 = price + 0.25;
    double f1 = this->getprice(x1);
    double f2 = this->getprice(x2);
    for (; !isZero(f1 - price); x2 = x1, x1 = price) {
        f1 = getprice(x1);
        f2 = getprice(x2);
        price = x1 - f1 * (x1 - x2) / (f1 - f2);
    }
    return price;
}

int main() {
    bond myBond = { 1000, 25, 6 };
    cout << "YTM is " << myBond.getytm(950) << endl;
    cout << "YTM is " << myBond.getytmsec(950) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your isZero() function source. Also,, when you say isn't working, what exactly do you mean.  Is it returning incorrect results, crashing, etc?

Comment: What does getPrice(double) do?  I suspect your problem is in the code, not the math but I need to be able to compile and run the code to see where the problem is.

Comment: I suggest that you copy and past your code into https://ideone.com/ or a similar online coding tool so you can make sure that it compiles.  Someone might be able to see your problem by just staring at it but I can't.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson Thank your for the suggestions on asking a better question. I copied my entire mini-program into the question above and also run it on ideone.com. It says, "time limit exceeded", which is also what happens on my computer.

Comment: Excellent!  I think if you are stepping through it you can see that the `getytm()` function is trapped once f2 is less than 0.  I'll peek at the online docs on bisect method but its been a few years, ok decades, since I did finance stuff.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3DuEhHqaWI Of course his link to his code is broken but he covers it well.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Even better:  His code: https://www.onlinegdb.com/HyYYnqxuf

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, a good way to debug this is to step through the calculations. Alternatively, you can print the relevant values at each iteration.

The problem is: find a zero to the function `f(x) = getprice(x) - price`.

The bisection method in general is: start with an interval `[low, high]` where `f(low)` and `f(high)` are of different signs (one non-positive, one non-negative). That means it contains a zero. Then choose either the left or right sub-interval based on the function value at the midpoint to maintain that property.

In this case, the function is monotonic and non-increasing so we know that `f(low)` must be the larger (non-negative) number and `f(high)` must be the smaller (non-positive) number. Therefore, we must choose the left sub-interval if `f(midpoint)` is negative, and choose the right sub-interval if `f(midpoint)` is positive. But the code does the opposite, choosing the right sub-interval if `f(midpoint)` is negative:

```
    x2 = (low + high) / 2;
    f2 = getprice(x2) - price;
    if (f2 < 0) {
        low = x2;
    }
```

So you choose smaller and smaller right sub-intervals with eventually `[low, high] = [1, 1]` and it is an infinite loop. Replace `f2 < 0` with `f2 > 0`.

The secant method generally involves taking two zero "estimates" `x_k` and `x_{k-1}` and uses a recurrence to find a better "estimate" `x_{k+1}`. The recurrence essentially uses the line between `(x_{k-1}, f(x_{k-1})` and `(x_k, f(x_k))` and looks where this line crosses zero.

The code provided has multiple problems. First, in the important step:

```
    price = x1 - f1 * (x1 - x2) / (f1 - f2);
```

where `x1` and `x2` are the current and previous estimates and `f1` is `getprice(x1)` and `f2` is `getprice(x2)`. Importantly, note that `f1` is not `f(x1)` where `f` is the function whose zero we want. This is not the secant formula. The first part of the second term should be the value of the function at `x1`, i.e. `f1 - price`, and not `f1`:

```
    ... = x1 - (f1 - price) * (x1 - x2) / (f1 - f2);
```

Secondly, you are assigning this to `price` and thus losing the actual value of `price` which you do need at each iteration.

Thirdly, the initial guesses for yield are `price` and `price + 0.25`. These are so far away from the actual value that it becomes a problem (the zero is a yield, between 0 and 1). Try `0` and `1`.

A lot of this could be avoided by not intermixing many concerns. You could factor out the logic of finding a zero of a function from the actual identity of the function. For example, one step of bisection is:

```
template<typename Function>
constexpr auto bisection_step(double low, double high, Function f) -> std::pair<double, double>
{
    assert(std::isfinite(high));
    assert(std::isfinite(low));
    assert(low < high);
    assert(f(low) * f(high) <= 0.);

    auto mid = midpoint(low, high);
    if (f(low) * f(mid) <= 0.)
        return {low, mid};
    else
        return {mid, high};
}
```

That lets you specify assumptions in the form of assertions or checks that throw exceptions or return error codes. That also makes the logic clearer, so one is less likely to select the wrong sub-interval. And even if one did, the assertion would fire.